# Grouping pandas data frame columns according to an external vector

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to calculate row sums of a pandas data frame for columns groupped according to an external vector. For example, for a matrix

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.array( [[1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50],[100,200,300,400,500]  ]  ))
matrix.columns =  ["T1", "T3", "T1", "T1", "T3"]
print(matrix)
    T1   T3   T1   T1   T3
0    1    2    3    4    5
1   10   20   30   40   50
2  100  200  300  400  500
```

the desired output is:

```
    T1  T2   T3
0    8   0    7
1   80   0   70
2  800   0  700
```

Therefore, I would like to group columns by a potentially broader vector that columns names (`matrix.columns`).

I obviosly tried:

```
matrix.groupby(matrix.columns, axis=1).sum()
    T1   T3
0    8    7
1   80   70
2  800  700
```

but this yields a differrent result.

I also tried:

```
matrix.groupby(["T1", "T2", "T3"], axis=1).sum()
```

but this results in an error.

Comment: ...there is no `t2` column.  you would have to create your own `t2` column as it does not exist in the `matrix.columns` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `T2` does not exist in `matrix.columns` one method would be to add it.

It could either be added as a new `zero value column` in the begining.

Alternatively, it could be added at the end (after the `groupby` is done).

here is an example of adding it after the groupby is done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.array( [[1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50],[100,200,300,400,500]  ]  ))
matrix.columns =  ["T1", "T3", "T1", "T1", "T3"]
print(matrix)

z = matrix.groupby(matrix.columns, axis=1).sum()
print(z)

columns_to_add = []
columns_you_want = ["T1", "T2", "T3"]
for c in columns_you_want:
    if c not in matrix.columns:
        # print('we want this', c)
        columns_to_add.append(c)

print('columns to add:', columns_to_add)

for c in columns_to_add:
    # Add a new column with default value 0
    print('adding', c)
    z[c] = 0
    

print(z)
```

the result is this:

```
    T1   T3   T1   T1   T3
0    1    2    3    4    5
1   10   20   30   40   50
2  100  200  300  400  500
    T1   T3
0    8    7
1   80   70
2  800  700
columns to add: ['T2']
adding T2
    T1   T3  T2
0    8    7   0
1   80   70   0
2  800  700   0
```